# PHP help me with this some notifications

Tags: php, forms, validation, submit, isset

I'm having a hard time figuring how to fix this notification. I already did it but the result was the code didn't work. My logic is not that high here is the code:

[Here is the error](http://prntscr.com/87iw3s).

Would you also explain why the gender is undeinfed but the textbox and textarea was just fine?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    <?php
        if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
            $x=$_POST['name'];
            $y=$_POST['email']; 
            $z=$_POST['website'];
            $c=$_POST['comment'];
            $v=$_POST['gender'];

            if($x == '' or $y == '' or $z==''or $c=='' or $v==''){
                echo "* required all fields";

            }else{

                 $result=$x.'<br>'.$y.'<br>'.$z.'<br>'.$c.'<br>'.$v;


            }
        }



    ?>
    <form action="" method="post">
      NAME:<input type="text" name="name"><br><br>
      EMAIL:<input type="text" name="email"><br><br>
      WEBSITE:<input type="text" name="website"><br><br>
      <textarea name="comment" rows="5" cols="40"></textarea><br><br>
      GENDER:<input type="radio" name="gender" value="Male">MALE
      <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Female">Female<br><br>
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
      </form>
      <?php
            echo "<h3>YOUR INPUT:</h3>";

            echo $result;


      ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: And "the code didnt work" does mean what? _Be specific_ if you expect a specific answer.

Comment: @evans_murira `or` is perfectly valid.

Answer (score 1):

```
if($x == '' ||$y == ''  || $z=='' || $c==''  || $v==''){
            echo "* required all fields";
        }else{
```

You cant user or man check the PHP manual

Answer (score 0):

try this way

```
if(($x="" || empty($x))&&($y="" || empty($y))&&($z="" || empty($z)))
{
  echo "* required all fields";
}
```

may be it will help

Comment: Usually it's considered good practice to explain something about your answer.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a `JS` function to validate your radio buttons at first, or you could also use the `HTML` attribute `required` (I have written both of them) followed by only a few `if-statements` This should work just fine.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
<script>
      function validateForm(){
            for(i=0; i<document.form.radios.length; i++){       
              if(document.form.radios[i].checked==false){
              c=1;
              }
                else{
                c=0;
                break;
                }}        

                if(c==1){
                alert('Please select an option');
                }
         }
 </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <?php
        if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
            $x=$_POST['name'];
            $y=$_POST['email']; 
            $z=$_POST['website'];
            $c=$_POST['comment'];

            if($x == '' or $y == '' or $z==''or $c=='')
            {                echo "* required all fields";

            }else{

                 $result=$x.'<br>'.$y.'<br>'.$z.'<br>'.$c;



            }
        }



    ?>
    <form action="" method="post">
      NAME:<input type="text" name="name"><br><br>
      EMAIL:<input type="text" name="email"><br><br>
      WEBSITE:<input type="text" name="website"><br><br>
      <textarea name="comment" rows="5" cols="40"></textarea><br><br>
     <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Male" required /> Male
      <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Female" /> Female
          <input type="submit" name = "submit" value="SAVE" />
      </form>
  <?php
  if(isset($_POST['submit']))
  {
   if(!($x == '' or $y == '' or $z==''or $c=='')){
        echo "<h3>YOUR INPUT:</h3>";

        echo $result;
  }else 
      echo "NOT ALL FIELDS WERE SELECTED.";}
  ?>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: what is the difference of !($x== '') to $x !=  ' '

Comment: @ShauiosbhaoiuAousiguosba, either way, you could do `!=` with every variable or if there are more conditions to be checked a simple `!(condition)` shouldn't hurt.

Comment: i tried to refractor your code and change it to $x != ' ' it gives me different output -_-

Comment: @ShauiosbhaoiuAousiguosba I assume you were trying this? `if($x != '' or $y != '' or $z != ''or $c != '')`

Answer (score 0):

You have some undefined variables.In order to make it work try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    <?php
    $result = '';
    $x = '';
    $y = '';
    $z = '';
    $c = '';
    $v = '';
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
     if(isset($_POST['name'])){
      $x= $_POST['name'];
     }
     if(isset($_POST['email'])){
      $y=$_POST['email'];
     }
     if(isset($_POST['website'])){
      $z=$_POST['website'];
     }
     if(isset($_POST['comment'])){
      $c=$_POST['comment'];
     }
     if(isset($_POST['gender'])){
      $v=$_POST['gender'];
     }
          .......
```

But you should separate your HTML code from the PHP,
maybe creating and index.html and from.php file.
Keeping all into the same file is a very bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

```
$v=isset($_POST['gender'])?$_POST['gender']:'';
```